# NAudio.MmException

Tags: c#, mp3, media-player, wav, naudio

I'm experimenting on how to play mp3 using Naudio. My simple app has one windows form and one button to play/pause the music. The app however has two major problem:

While it was intended that if the music is playing and the play button is pressed, the app should stop playing. Instead when the button is re-pressed, the app restart the music and then (sometime) throw an exception
If the button is pressed two or three times (and  without any delay) ,the app throw a NAudio.MmException (Message=InvalidParameter calling acmStreamClose)
Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code? Below is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace NaudioTesting
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private NAudio.Wave.BlockAlignReductionStream stream = null;

        private NAudio.Wave.DirectSoundOut output = null;


        public void LoadFile(string filePath)
        {
            DisposeWave();

            if (filePath.EndsWith(".mp3"))
            {
                NAudio.Wave.WaveStream pcm =
                    NAudio.Wave.WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(new NAudio.Wave.Mp3FileReader(filePath));
                stream = new NAudio.Wave.BlockAlignReductionStream(pcm);
            }
            else if (filePath.EndsWith(".wav"))
            {
                NAudio.Wave.WaveStream pcm = new NAudio.Wave.WaveChannel32(new NAudio.Wave.WaveFileReader(filePath));
                stream = new NAudio.Wave.BlockAlignReductionStream(pcm);
            }
            else throw new InvalidOperationException("Not a correct audio file type.");

            output = new NAudio.Wave.DirectSoundOut();
            output.Init(stream);
            output.Play();
        }

        private void playPauseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string filePath = "GetLoud.mp3";
            LoadFile(filePath);
            if (output != null)
            {
                if (output.PlaybackState == NAudio.Wave.PlaybackState.Playing) output.Pause();
                else if (output.PlaybackState == NAudio.Wave.PlaybackState.Paused) output.Play();
            }
        }

        private void DisposeWave()
        {
            try
            {
                if (output != null)
                {
                    if (output.PlaybackState == NAudio.Wave.PlaybackState.Playing) output.Stop();
                    output.Dispose();
                    output = null;
                }
                if (stream != null)
                {
                    stream.Dispose();
                    stream = null;
                }
            }
            catch (NAudio.MmException)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            DisposeWave();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [DirectSoundOut](http://naudio.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/e43c857bbbe2#NAudio/Wave/WaveOutputs/DirectSoundOut.cs) source, the implementation for Play and Pause doesn't support resuming. Namely, what happens to you is exactly what it should. Calling play will always start from begining of the stream.
You should use `WaveOut` instead. It supports resuming by calling `Play` again, just like what you have in your code.

```
output = new NAudio.Wave.WaveOut();
```

Comment: I am not sure if I am putting the above snippet in the right place but whenever I do this I get this syntax error: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'NAudio.Wave.WaveOut' to 'NAudio.Wave.DirectSoundOut". Does this means I should not use DirectSoundOut at all?

Comment: You should change the declaration of `private NAudio.Wave.DirectSoundOut output = null;` into `private NAudio.Wave.WaveOutoutput = null;`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Your suggestions were so helpful. Indeed, it seems I had to issues. The first one was that I was using directsoundOut instead of WaveOut. The second one is that I wasn't checking if the output was null on every button click.